# Making this line pylint correct

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
MS = 'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: %s:%d\r\nMAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\nMX: 2\r\nST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n' % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

On checking this line with [PEP8](http://pep8online.com/), it says "line too long"

So I break it like this:

```
MS = 'M-SEARCH * 
      HTTP/1.1\r\n
      HOST: %s:%d\r\n
      MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n
      MX: 2\r\n
      ST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n
      ' % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

But I am still getting so many errors.

Please review this.

Comment: It seems your question is about "But I am still getting so many errors", but you're not saying what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python's implicit string concatenation and implicit line concatenation inside unterminated brackets/parenthesis...:

```
MS = ('M-SEARCH * '
      'HTTP/1.1\r\n'
      'HOST: %s:%d\r\n'
      'MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n'
      'MX: 2\r\n'
      'ST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n') % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

Note that some ([including Guido](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-May/020527.html)) seem to dislike implicit string concatenation.  If you fall into that category, you can use *explicit* concatenation (just add a `+`'s where necessary).  There's no real harm in doing this -- the bytecode optimizer will optimize the concatenation away just the same as it does with implicit concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Use Python's multiline strings:

```
MS = """M-SEARCH * 
      HTTP/1.1\r\n
      HOST: %s:%d\r\n
      MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n
      MX: 2\r\n
      ST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n
      """ % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

But be aware that this will change indentation and add extra newlines (which might or might not be a concern for your use case).

Comment: This is going to add extra newlines isn't it?

Comment: yes it will. the parentheses notation works best in this regard.

Comment: Yes, I added a note saying that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't break strings like that. Use a backslash:

```
MS = 'M-SEARCH * \
HTTP/1.1\r\n \
HOST: %s:%d\r\n \
MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n \
MX: 2\r\n \
ST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n \
' % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

Or use triple-quotes. This will add newlines so you can drop the last `\n` in your strings:

```
MS = """M-SEARCH * 
HTTP/1.1\r
HOST: %s:%d\r
MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r
MX: 2\r
ST: ssdp:all\r\n\r
""" % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

Notice that the indentation matters in both cases.

If you're generating HTTP requests, there are plenty of libraries for that. Why not use one? Check out [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [`urllib3`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Both of these versions add an extra level of indentation to the second line onward.  Not sure if that matters or not for the application.

Comment: for the  formatting of the statement which Patrick shared, I think @msvalkon solution is better. If one needs newline frequently in the long string, its better to avoid \n. ofcourse, that would mean making newline implicit and Guido may not like it :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I think would work for now. Splitting the lines into strings.

```
MS = 'M-SEARCH *' + \
  'HTTP/1.1\r\n' + \
  'HOST: %s:%d\r\n' + \
  'MAN: "ssdp:discover"\r\n' + \
  'MX: 2\r\n' + \
  'ST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n' % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```

Comment: this is the third alternative but it needs lots of extra plus and backslashes which is bit cumbersome and interferes in code reading

Comment: @comiventor -- FWIW, as linked in my answer, there's a growing population of people who like the `+`s arguing that it is more _explicit_.  pylint will likely complain about the backslashes in favor of continuation within parenthesis though.

Answer (score 0):

enclosing within brackets is an alternative solution
I use it extensively to tackle this long line issue

including @mgilson suggestion to include + to be explicit

```
MS = ("M-SEARCH *" +
  "HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
  "HOST: %s:%d\r\n" +
  "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n" +
  "MX: 2\r\n" +
  "ST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n") % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)
```